# Javascript timestamp to date

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, amcharts

Can anybody help me with this, it's driving me crazy. I'm begginer with Javascript, and i encountered problem with dates for the first time now.

I have already asked this, but no one answered me:
[json with parsed time or timestamp to amchartss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675061/json-with-parsed-time-or-timestamp-to-amcharts)

Basically i have this XHR call.

```
 getJSON = function(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status == 200) {
            chartLoad(xhr.response);
            console.log(xhr.response);
        } else {
            console.log("oh shit");
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

I'm getting in response here JSON file with timestamp, how can i convert all timestamps to date YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm.

Before instead of timestamps i had date string converted directly on server, in that way i didn't need to do converting on client side, but this way work only on Chrome.

HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there's no native date.format method in JavaScript you can grow your own for one off implementations. In your case something like:

```
var newDate = new Date(myTimeStamp);

var outDate = newDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+newDate.getDate()+" "+newDate.getHours()+":"+newDate.getMinutes();
```

For todays date that will output: `2014-5-15 16:7`
Note the `+1` for getMonth which starts counting at 0
Might need an extra bit of fiddling if you want to ensure always two digits on values (ie leading zeros on single digits)

To do this within the xhr onload handler might be something like this:

```
           xhr.onload = function (e) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    var blob = this.response;

                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.onload = function (e) {
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src); // Clean up after yourself.
                    };
                    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    document.body.appendChild(img);

                    var myTimeStamp = e.timeStamp;
                    //I would probably want to put this date code
                    //in a separate function somewhere
                    var newDate = new Date(myTimeStamp);
                    var outDate = newDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+newDate.getDate()+" "+newDate.getHours()+":"+newDate.getMinutes();
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = outDate;
                    document.body.appendChild(div);
                }
            };
```

Comment: Got it, just one more question how would i apply this to all timestamps from xhr?

Comment: I think I would wrap it in a function and then call it within each "onreadystatechange" handler. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jack or "onload" handler in your case.

Comment: @Jack or do you mean extracting the timeStamp value from the onload event?

Comment: I meant do i need to do foreach cycle or there is another way? Thank you.

Comment: @Jack the xhr.onload should be called for each xhr call you make to the server - so in that way you don't need any loop. I assume you are making a number of xhr calls to the server to retrieve assets. Perhaps it is these calls that need to be in a loop?

Comment: Actually i made a separate function that convert timestamp to date, what i dont understand is if i have json response like [{timestamp,..},{timestamp,..},{timestamp, ..},{timestamp,..}]. Do i need to do foreach, or timestamp will be parsed directly in xhr.onload like in your example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52794/discussion-between-steve-mc-and-jack)

Answer (score 1):

I like using moment.js for my datetime parsing and formatting needs:

http://momentjs.com/

Code ends up like this:

```
moment(some_timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

Comment: I prefer doing it in vanilla JS, i learn better in that way :)

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial might clear things up for you :)

http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/time-series-chart-the-great-advantages-of-parsing-dates/

Comment: Solved, but i'll have it in mind for future reference :) Thanks!