# how to split date to formatted date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am getting a date like

```
20160509125119040
```

from back end database.
I need to change it like

```
 2016-05-09 12:51:19
```

in javascript.plz help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript timestamp to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681273/javascript-timestamp-to-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var string = "20160509125119040";
    var date = string.substr(0,4) + "-" + string.substr(4,2) + "-" + string.substr(6,2) + " " + string.substr(8,2) + ":" + string.substr(10,2) + ":" + string.substr(12,2);
    console.log(date);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/7yq6zxLk/

```
  var n = 20160509125119040;
  var formatDate = n.substring(0,4) + "-" + n.substring(4,6) + "-" + n.substring(6,8) + " " + n.substring(8,10) + ":" + n.substring(10, 12) + ":" + n.substring(12, 14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dd ="20160509125119040";
var year = dd.substring(0, 4); var month = dd.substring(4).substring(0, 2); var date = dd.substring(6).substring(0, 2)
var hour = dd.substring(8).substring(0, 2); var min = dd.substring(10).substring(0, 2); var sec = dd.substring(12).substring(0, 2)
var finaldate = year+"-"+month+"-"+date+" "+hour+":"+min+":"+ sec;
alert(finaldate)
```